# Xml layout preview and activity while running are inconsistent each other

Tags: android, android-studio

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_name_profile_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/name_profile_hint"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_name_fragment_profile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:text="mio_nome"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_lastname_profile_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/last_name_profile_hint"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_lastname_fragment_profile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="mio_cognome" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_email_profile_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email_profile_fragment_hint"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_email_fragment_profile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text="mia_email"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_password_profile_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password_profile_hint"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
                app:endIconTint="@android:color/white">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_password_fragment_profile"
                    android:text="mia_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_nickname_profile_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="20">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_nickname_fragment_profile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="mio_username"
                    android:maxLines="1" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my ProfileFragment.java class

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextLastName;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextUsername;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    private View view;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        initializeViewComponents();
        initializeController();
        return view;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void initializeViewComponents() {
        editTextName = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name_fragment_profile);
        editTextLastName = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_lastname_fragment_profile);
        editTextEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_email_fragment_profile);
        editTextUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_nickname_fragment_profile);
        editTextPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password_fragment_profile);
        floatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_edit_profile_fragment);
    }

    public void initializeController() {
        ProfileController profileController = new ProfileController(this);
        profileController.setListenersOnProfileFragment();
    }

    public EditText getEditTextPassword() {
        return editTextPassword;
    }

    public FloatingActionButton getFloatingActionButton() {
        return floatingActionButton;
    }

    public EditText getEditTextName() {
        return editTextName;
    }

    public EditText getEditTextLastName() {
        return editTextLastName;
    }

    public EditText getEditTextUsername() {
        return editTextUsername;
    }

    public EditText getEditTextEmail() {
        return editTextEmail;
    }
}
```

And this is my ProfileController class

```
public class ProfileController implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ProfileFragment profileFragment;
    private Account account;
    private AccountDAO accountDAO;
    private DAOFactory daoFactory;

    public ProfileController(ProfileFragment profileFragment) {
        this.profileFragment = profileFragment;
        account = new Account(profileFragment.getEditTextName().getText().toString(),
                profileFragment.getEditTextLastName().getText().toString(),
                profileFragment.getEditTextUsername().getText().toString(),
                profileFragment.getEditTextEmail().getText().toString(),
                profileFragment.getEditTextPassword().getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.floating_action_button_edit_profile_fragment:
                showPasswordDialog();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void showPasswordDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(profileFragment.getActivity());
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = profileFragment.requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_request_password, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.verify, null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        setOnClickListenerDialogInsertPassword(dialog);
    }

    private void setOnClickListenerDialogInsertPassword(final AlertDialog dialog) {
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editTextPasswordInsertedInDialog = dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_input_edit_text_password_modify_profile);
                String passwordInsetedInDialog = editTextPasswordInsertedInDialog.getText().toString();
                if (account.getPassword().equals(passwordInsetedInDialog)) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    showInsertNewPasswordDialog();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(profileFragment.getContext(), "Le password non coincidono", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showInsertNewPasswordDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(profileFragment.getActivity());
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = profileFragment.requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_insert_new_password, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.verify, null)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        setOnClickListenerDialogInsertNewPasswordPositiveButton(dialog);
    }

    private void setOnClickListenerDialogInsertNewPasswordPositiveButton(final AlertDialog dialog) {
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editTextNewPassword = dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_input_edit_text_insert_password);
                EditText editTextRepeatNewPassword = dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_input_edit_text_repeat_password);
                if (editTextNewPassword.getText().toString().equals(editTextRepeatNewPassword.getText().toString())) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    doUpdatePassword(editTextNewPassword.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(profileFragment.getContext(), "Le password non coincidono", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void setListenersOnProfileFragment() {
        profileFragment.getFloatingActionButton().setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void doUpdatePassword(String newPassword) {
        daoFactory = DAOFactory.getInstance();
        accountDAO = daoFactory.getAccountDAO(ConfigFileReader.getProperty("account_storage_technology",
                profileFragment.requireActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        if (accountDAO.updatePassword(account, profileFragment.getContext(), newPassword)) {
            Toast.makeText(profileFragment.requireActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Password aggiornata", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(profileFragment.requireActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Password non aggiornata", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately its preview layout [xml preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zziWA.png) is pretty different from actual one [actual one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f95Zk.png). As you can see, in the actual running activity there is not "email" input layout meanwhile it is present in the xml layout preview.

- What's the matter? How can I fix this problem?

This is driving me insane. I think the problem is in the nesting in the xml file.ù

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

I do not see what the problem could be from (this) code alone.
Are you positive that you are not accidentally hiding it in `Java`/`Kotlin` code?

Sometimes, old caches can be the culprit. Try cleaning the project and then running it again (`Android Studio -> Build -> Clean project`)

Comment: Cleaning my project did not work. I edited my post attaching ProfileFragment class

Comment: The only thing I can think of now is `ProfileController`. What does it do?

If that's not the problem, I'd go with `Layout Inspector` to try seeing if the label is even there and what it's contents are.

Furthermore I'd stop the app, close Android Studio and deleted all `build` directories for that particular project.

Comment: I edited my post attaching Profile Controller class

Comment: I can't find the problem. While waiting for someone smarter than me to respond, try restarting, resetting, rebuilding, etc. everything :)